# Is there a way to show that this ode system is asymptotically stable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Suppose we have

$$\dot{x} = -\frac{x}{y+a} $$

$$\dot{y} = -y$$ for $a>0$,

Is the above system asymptotically stable?

Now, I know that we can solve for $y$ as

$$y = y(0) e^{-t}$$

and we can choose for the $x$ part of the system, a Lyapunov function as $V(x) = 0.5 x^2$ and thus obtain the derivative:

$$\dot{V} = -\frac{x^2}{y(0) e^{-t} + a}$$

which $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} \dot{V} =  -\frac{x^2}{a}$.

But, I don't think this is correct.

Is there a way to prove the $x,y$ system is stable, just by finding a positive definite Lyapunov function and proving that its derivative is negative definite?

Comment: edited some typos, gave more context, and deleted the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the general solution of the DE system:
$$\left\{y(t)\to e^{-t} y_0,x(t)\to x_0 (a+y_0)^{1/a} \left(a e^t+y_0\right)^{-1/a}\right\}$$

Get the limits for $t \to \infty$:

$$\underset{t\to \infty }{\text{lim}}x(t)=\fbox{$0\text{ if }\left(x_0\left|(a+y_0)^{1/a}\right|y_0\right)\in \mathbb{R}\land a>0$}$$

$$\underset{t\to \infty }{\text{lim}}y(t)=0$$

Hence the system is asymptotically stable for $a>0$ and $a+y_0>0$.

Comment: It seems that if $a > 0$ and $a < -c_{1}$, singularity can occur at some time $t$ as $a e^{t} \rightarrow -c_{1}$. The system is not globally asymptotically stable.